# Can we get an un-obfuscated version of the vote object?

Tags: support, voting, stack-exchange

Many of us want to write scripts on top of stackoverflow, and many of these would need to extend or reconnect the [vote object](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/question.js?v=4058). My recent attempt to build an auto-page-loader was made difficult over not being able to properly inspect the vote object.

I understand that SO doesn't have much time to invest in making an API, but could we at least get a copy of the unobfuscated vote object?

**Note**: I'm not asking about formatting.

Comment: I may be more inclined to help if you explain how you want to extend the object. I don't currently see of any ways to extend it in a meaningful way that would last after page reload.

Comment: @Ian, with all due respect, I don't think incredulity should be a reason *not* to release something. While it may be true that you don't have ideas of what can be done, other's may. And consider also the fact that once the object is plainly visible, more ideas may come as a result of understanding what is possible.

Comment: I think my earlier comment was somewhat misdirected. I was trying to be helpful, but since it would involve an investment of time I was simply curious of what you had planned for it as I don't want to spend my time on something that won't be used. If you only want the code directly from Jeff that's fine, but I was only trying to help.

Comment: @Ian, my interest is primarily geared by curiosity. Kinda interested in seeing what I may be able to do. In all honesty, I don't have a specific plan in sight - just wanting to play a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using http://jsbeautifier.org/, which at least makes the code look nicer...

Comment: I know that. I'm not asking about formatting. I'm asking about obfuscation. Variables named A, c, X, T and functions named Z, b, R, and e aren't very informative.

Comment: Ahh, fair enough!